# How is it possible to export a Cloud Genomics variantset to BigQuery now that varientsets.export has been deprecated?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-genomics

I have loaded a variantset into Cloud Genomics and am attempting to export it to BigQuery. The first approach I tried was to use a pipeline as detailed here:

https://cloud.google.com/genomics/docs/how-tos/load-variants

However, 20 minutes into the process, it failed. According to StackDriver error reporting, it appears to be a problem in the VCF file, though I am at a loss to explain how it might be fixed:

```
ValueError: Invalid record in VCF file. Error: list index out of range
at next (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gcp_variant_transforms/beam_io/vcfio.py:476)
at read_records (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gcp_variant_transforms/beam_io/vcfio.py:398)
at dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start (native_operations.py:48)
at dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start (native_operations.py:44)
at dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start (native_operations.py:39)
at dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start (native_operations.py:38)
at execute (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py:167)
at do_work (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py:609)
```

So I continued to search for other options. I turned to the API:

https://cloud.google.com/genomics/reference/rest/v1/variantsets/export

I made sure that my account was a BigQuery admin and an owner for the Genoimcs variantset. I used the following parameters:

```
{
  "projectId": "my-project",
  "format": "FORMAT_BIGQUERY",
  "bigqueryDataset": "my_dataset",
  "bigqueryTable": "new_table"
}
```

Upon submitting, I receive the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Unknown Error.",
    "status": "UNKNOWN"
  }
}
```

I have also tried this from the command line: `gcloud alpha genomics variantsets export variantset_id bigquery_table --bigquery-dataset=my-dataset --bigquery-project=my-project`.

But that gives me a 500 Unknown Error as well. I've been going back on this for several hours, and the documentation is quite sparse.

Please, what could I be missing?

Comment: When running the pipeline, you should be able to see the error logs in the Dataflow Console. Does it work with a [public dataset](https://cloud.google.com/genomics/docs/public-datasets/illumina-platinum-genomes)?

Comment: A public dataset fails as well. I took a look at the Dataflow Console error logs. There are four steps, each of them laabled "Failed": ReadfromVcf, FilterVariants, ProcessVaraints, VarianttoBigQuery. Clicking on each of them displays "No entries found for selected log." The spelling of "ProcessVaraints" is not my typo, but Google's.

Comment: I have updated my original post to include a StackDriver error. The problem is in the VCF file, itself. If you have any idea how this might be resolved, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one or more lines in the VCF file are malformed and do not conform to the [spec](http://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.3.pdf).

We just released a preprocessor/validator tool that shows a report of all such malformed records. Please give it a try: https://github.com/googlegenomics/gcp-variant-transforms/blob/master/docs/vcf_files_preprocessor.md (please run with `--report_all_conflicts` to ensure you get the full report).

If it turns out that only a few records are malformed, then you can either fix them manually in the VCF file or run the `vcf_to_bq` pipeline with `--allow_malformed_records`, which will skip the malformed ones (just logs them) and load the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking this question. We deprecated the `Variants API` six months ago because we found that the #1 thing people did with it was **BQ** export.

So, we released a brand new **FOSS tool**, Variant Transforms, that simply does this task, but is more performant.

[Link](https://github.com/googlegenomics/gcp-variant-transforms)

We actually just had a new release this week. Please take a look and let us know what you think.

In addition to the code & docs, you'll see much our product **roadmap** there, too.

Please comment and share your thoughts!

FYI, we'll be decommissioning the `Variants API` soon.

Jonathan (PM, biomedical data, Google Cloud)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Unfortunately, the FOSS tool does not work (see above). Dataflow Console logs show "Failed" at every step of the process.